# R - Error in seq.default(h[1], h[2], length = n)?

Tags: r, shiny

I have this dummy data:

```
> dput(mergedDf)
structure(list(particles = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 
1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 
5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 
5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 
10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 50, 50, 50), timestamp = c(1477554578237, 
1477554580104, 1477554580405, 1477554580621, 1477554580829, 1477554581048, 
1477554581264, 1477128810777, 1477128812460, 1477128812666, 1477128812836, 
1477128813036, 1477128813217, 1477128813386, 1477128813568, 1477128813769, 
1477128813957, 1477128814128, 1477128814330, 1477128814513, 1477128814689, 
1477128814881, 1477128815063, 1477128815425, 1477128815639, 1477128815853, 
1477128816089, 1477128816299, 1477128816497, 1477554458704, 1477554461195, 
1477554461478, 1477554461700, 1477554461925, 1477554462142, 1477554462365, 
1477554462561, 1477554462795, 1477554463015, 1477554469995, 1477554470234, 
1477554470441, 1477554470658, 1477554470869, 1477554471066, 1477554471287, 
1477554471531, 1477554471827, 1477563960753, 1477564132825, 1477638346229, 
1477638489644, 1477638506435, 1477128819834, 1477128821680, 1477128821901, 
1477128822101, 1477128822277, 1477128822452, 1477128822637, 1477128822833, 
1477128823013, 1477128823177, 1477128823534, 1477128823726, 1477128823926, 
1477128824165, 1477128824350, 1477128824720, 1477128824910, 1477128825092, 
1477128825293, 1477128798198, 1477128804065, 1477128804277, 1477128804477, 
1477128804657, 1477128804849, 1477128805007, 1477128805375, 1477128805575, 
1477128805775, 1477128805992, 1477128806232, 1477554117958, 1477554123118, 
1477554429609, 1477554557560, 1477554559596, 1477554559858, 1477554560138, 
1477554560370, 1477554560618, 1477554560884, 1477636388874, 1477554450626, 
1477554452687, 1477554452916, 1477554453174, 1477554453376, 1477554486384, 
1477554488340, 1477554488568, 1477554488797, 1477554489216, 1477554489490, 
1477554489769, 1477554504746, 1477554504992, 1477554505214, 1477554505439, 
1477554505679, 1477554505901, 1477554610058, 1477554611656, 1477554611915, 
1477128829412, 1477128831017, 1477128831262, 1477128831504, 1477128831688, 
1477128831880, 1477128832041, 1477128832242, 1477128832400, 1477128832600, 
1477128832769, 1477128832928, 1477128833107, 1477128833278, 1477128833471, 
1477128833632, 1477128833808, 1477129018233, 1477129018435, 1477129018649, 
1477129018833, 1477129019029, 1477129019219, 1477129019411, 1477129019596, 
1477129019787, 1477129019981, 1477129020198, 1477554474735, 1477554476443, 
1477554476641, 1477554477049, 1477554477291, 1477554477498, 1477554477694, 
1477554477891, 1477554478123, 1477129029789, 1477129032262, 1477129032486, 
1477129032688, 1477129032884, 1477129033085, 1477129033278, 1477129033458, 
1477129033647, 1477129033831, 1477129034028, 1477129034206, 1477129034408, 
1477129034610, 1477129034824, 1477554549825, 1477554551833, 1477554552088, 
1477554552493, 1477554552703, 1477554552913, 1477554553111, 1477554553330, 
1477554553592, 1477554553857, 1477554554107, 1477554601052, 1477554602988, 
1477554603250), date = structure(c(1477554578.237, 1477554580.104, 
1477554580.405, 1477554580.621, 1477554580.829, 1477554581.048, 
1477554581.264, 1477128810.777, 1477128812.46, 1477128812.666, 
1477128812.836, 1477128813.036, 1477128813.217, 1477128813.386, 
1477128813.568, 1477128813.769, 1477128813.957, 1477128814.128, 
1477128814.33, 1477128814.513, 1477128814.689, 1477128814.881, 
1477128815.063, 1477128815.425, 1477128815.639, 1477128815.853, 
1477128816.089, 1477128816.299, 1477128816.497, 1477554458.704, 
1477554461.195, 1477554461.478, 1477554461.7, 1477554461.925, 
1477554462.142, 1477554462.365, 1477554462.561, 1477554462.795, 
1477554463.015, 1477554469.995, 1477554470.234, 1477554470.441, 
1477554470.658, 1477554470.869, 1477554471.066, 1477554471.287, 
1477554471.531, 1477554471.827, 1477563960.753, 1477564132.825, 
1477638346.229, 1477638489.644, 1477638506.435, 1477128819.834, 
1477128821.68, 1477128821.901, 1477128822.101, 1477128822.277, 
1477128822.452, 1477128822.637, 1477128822.833, 1477128823.013, 
1477128823.177, 1477128823.534, 1477128823.726, 1477128823.926, 
1477128824.165, 1477128824.35, 1477128824.72, 1477128824.91, 
1477128825.092, 1477128825.293, 1477128798.198, 1477128804.065, 
1477128804.277, 1477128804.477, 1477128804.657, 1477128804.849, 
1477128805.007, 1477128805.375, 1477128805.575, 1477128805.775, 
1477128805.992, 1477128806.232, 1477554117.958, 1477554123.118, 
1477554429.609, 1477554557.56, 1477554559.596, 1477554559.858, 
1477554560.138, 1477554560.37, 1477554560.618, 1477554560.884, 
1477636388.874, 1477554450.626, 1477554452.687, 1477554452.916, 
1477554453.174, 1477554453.376, 1477554486.384, 1477554488.34, 
1477554488.568, 1477554488.797, 1477554489.216, 1477554489.49, 
1477554489.769, 1477554504.746, 1477554504.992, 1477554505.214, 
1477554505.439, 1477554505.679, 1477554505.901, 1477554610.058, 
1477554611.656, 1477554611.915, 1477128829.412, 1477128831.017, 
1477128831.262, 1477128831.504, 1477128831.688, 1477128831.88, 
1477128832.041, 1477128832.242, 1477128832.4, 1477128832.6, 1477128832.769, 
1477128832.928, 1477128833.107, 1477128833.278, 1477128833.471, 
1477128833.632, 1477128833.808, 1477129018.233, 1477129018.435, 
1477129018.649, 1477129018.833, 1477129019.029, 1477129019.219, 
1477129019.411, 1477129019.596, 1477129019.787, 1477129019.981, 
1477129020.198, 1477554474.735, 1477554476.443, 1477554476.641, 
1477554477.049, 1477554477.291, 1477554477.498, 1477554477.694, 
1477554477.891, 1477554478.123, 1477129029.789, 1477129032.262, 
1477129032.486, 1477129032.688, 1477129032.884, 1477129033.085, 
1477129033.278, 1477129033.458, 1477129033.647, 1477129033.831, 
1477129034.028, 1477129034.206, 1477129034.408, 1477129034.61, 
1477129034.824, 1477554549.825, 1477554551.833, 1477554552.088, 
1477554552.493, 1477554552.703, 1477554552.913, 1477554553.111, 
1477554553.33, 1477554553.592, 1477554553.857, 1477554554.107, 
1477554601.052, 1477554602.988, 1477554603.25), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC-1"), site = c("16", "16", "16", "16", 
"16", "16", "16", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", 
"17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", 
"17", "17", "17", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", 
"16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", 
"17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", 
"17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", 
"17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", 
"17", "17", "17", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", 
"16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", 
"16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", 
"16", "16", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", 
"17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", 
"17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "16", "16", "16", 
"16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", 
"17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "16", 
"16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", 
"16", "16"), code = c("16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", 
"17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", 
"17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", 
"16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", 
"16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "17", "17", "17", 
"17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", 
"17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", 
"17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", 
"16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", 
"16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", 
"16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "17", 
"17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", 
"17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", 
"17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", 
"16", "16", "16", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", 
"17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "16", "16", "16", "16", 
"16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16"), 
    key_date = c("2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", 
    "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", 
    "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", 
    "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", 
    "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", 
    "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", 
    "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", 
    "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", 
    "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", 
    "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", 
    "2016-10-27", "2016-10-28", "2016-10-28", "2016-10-28", "2016-10-22", 
    "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", 
    "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", 
    "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", 
    "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", 
    "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", 
    "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", 
    "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", 
    "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", 
    "2016-10-28", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", 
    "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", 
    "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", 
    "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", 
    "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", 
    "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", 
    "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", 
    "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", 
    "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", 
    "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", 
    "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", 
    "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-22", 
    "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", 
    "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", 
    "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-27", 
    "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", 
    "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", 
    "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27")), .Names = c("particles", 
"timestamp", "date", "site", "code", "key_date"), row.names = c(NA, 
-182L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to plot this data with openair:

```
## first drop site name
thedata <- subset(mergedDf, select = -site)

# Load package.
library(reshape2)

## now reshape the data using the reshape package
thedata <- melt(thedata, id.vars = c("date", "code"))
thedata <- dcast(thedata, ... ~ code + variable)

# Empty vector for storing line_pollutants later.
line_pollutants <- c()

selectedStream1Title <- '17'

selectedSpecies <- 'particles'

# Concat the string.
stream1PollutantCode <- paste(selectedStream1Title, "_", selectedSpecies, sep = "")

# Append the data to the list.
line_pollutants <- append(line_pollutants, stream1PollutantCode)

selectedStream2Title <- '16'

selectedSpecies <- 'particles'

# Concat the string.
stream2PollutantCode <- paste(selectedStream2Title, "_", selectedSpecies, sep = "")

# Append the data to the list.
line_pollutants <- append(line_pollutants, stream2PollutantCode)

# Load openair for plotting the data.
library("openair")
```

The function:

```
timePlot(
    thedata,
    pollutant = line_pollutants,
    avg.time = "1 min", << this causes the error...
    group = TRUE,
    lwd = 2
)
```

Error:

```
Error in seq.default(h[1], h[2], length = n) : 
  'to' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite
```

What does it mean?

But it is fine with `avg.time = "default"`:

```
timePlot(
    thedata,
    pollutant = line_pollutants,
    avg.time = "default",
    group = TRUE,
    lwd = 2
)
```

Why does `avg.time = "1 min"` cause the error above? Is it something wrong with my data or something else?

Any ideas?